# Apache Rewrite to simulate a new document root for a directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm currently using a web app (Elastik) which currently doesn't support being installed in a sub-directory. Since I can't make sub-domains on the server at the moment, I was wondering if I could use Rewrite Rules to redirect any request referred from that directory, back to itself, since all linked files are specified in relation to the root directory. I have tried a few things, and I think this is the closest I've got:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /elastik/
RewriteCond %{REFERER} ^http://localhost/elastik/.*$
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ $[1]
```

But this still doesn't work! Can anyone help point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured this one out, using htaccess and php combined. I'll leave this here in the case that someone else runs into this situation, which I was unable to find any help on the internet on

Firstly you need to move all your normal website files into a subdirectory, that I've called "normal" for this purpose, so your files now look like this:

```
>public_html
    >normal
        >index.php
        >other
        >files
    >elastik
        >all
        >elastic
        >files
```

Now create a .htaccess file to redirect everything to an index.php file in public_html that looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

And then the index.php file in the public_html directory should look something like this:

```
<?php 
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])){
    if(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], "localhost/elastik")){
    header("Location: /elastik".$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    }
    else{
    $uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    header("Location: /normal".$uri);
    }
}
else{
    header("Location: /normal".$uri);
}
?>
```

I had to move my php includes that are referred to in ralation to the document root, back into the public_html directory, but after I did that, everything else runs smoothly